# Validate model relation with factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a basic model

```
class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region  
  validates :region, :presence => true
end
```

I expect a province without region was invalid.

So I've a test like that.

```
it 'Must have a region' do
  province = create(:province)
  expect(province.valid?).to be_false
end
```

Fixture is make with factory girl.

```
factory :province do
  name 'a_name'
end
```

The test fails :

```
1) Province Initialization Must have a region
 Failure/Error: expect(province.valid?).to be_false
   expected: false value
        got: true
```

any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Can the factory actually create one of these things? creation involves validation and you don't have anything defined in the factory itself to account for the association...that doesn't really explain why the expectation itself is failing though.

Comment: Have you defined any default value in your schema for province?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after restart the computer, test passed as espected. So I suppose rspec doesn't refresh the model after I put the validation. I don't know why.